# JavaScript can't retrieve FileReader variable

Tags: javascript, closures, filereader

I'm attempting to retrieve a certain field from a record from within a .CSV file.  I cannot access the `record` variable after the onload function.

```
var record;

//FileReader to read contents of CSV
var reader = new FileReader();


var file = document.getElementById('csvFileUploadID').files[0];

reader.onload = function(event) {
    reader.readAsText(document.getElementById('csvFileUploadID').files[0]);
    record = reader.result.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/)[1];
    record = record.split(',')[1]
};

//Can't access the 'record' variable here.
```

I'm aware that the solution to this issue is likely related to closure, however, I can't quite wrap my head around the concept.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: onload is async.

Comment: Yep-- record probably isn't loaded by the time you're trying to manipulate it outside of `onload`-- need to encapsulate that functionality and put it in a function to call at the end of your `onload` manipulation.  Also, I can't see the rest of your code, but make sure not to use variables w/o a variable declaration (that may not be the case, depending on your other code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of promises to handle this sort of async code.

```
var file = document.getElementById('csvFileUploadID').files[0];

function readRecord(file) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        reader.readAsText(document.getElementById('csvFileUploadID').files[0]);
        record = reader.result.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/)[1];
        record = record.split(',')[1];
        resolve(record);
    };
  });
};


readRecord(file).then(function(record) {
 // access record here
});
```

Comment: Technically, this is an error, because [`const/let` declarations don't get hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_Dead_Zone_and_errors_with_let) (I assume you're used to babel which converts these to `var` and so the code still works :) ). You should use `readRecord` after you define it.

Comment: I hate to ask, but would you mind revising this so that it does not have the arrow function expressions?  Not playing nice with my IDE, and I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @AlexanderEdwards add a `function` keyword and remove the `=>`

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using an angular solution, but I'm sure this will do the trick as well.